# elasticsearch query by array of id result returned is not sorted by the array of id pass in

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, elastica

I am using elastica and below is my query :

```
    $query = new Query();

    $query->setSize(5);

    $qb = new \Elastica\Query\Ids();

    $qb->addId("id_5");
    $qb->addId("id_3");
    $qb->addId("id_4");
    $qb->addId("id_1");
    $qb->addId("id_2");

    return $query->setQuery($qb)
```

I want the result return in the same order as what I passed in for example in this case it will be **"id_5, id_3, id_4, id_1, id_2"**

however what i get is the sorting is not the same as what I wanted

Comment: Do you have id as part of document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this as two solution 
1. if you have id as part of document then you can do

```
POST indexName/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": "sortOrder.indexOf(doc['Id'].value)",
        "params": {
          "sortOrder": [
            "AVMX9sHTyNVr4SjF3oRt",
            "AVMTc1fSyNVr4SjF3WpF",
            "AVMYuGLOyNVr4SjF3rKm"
          ]
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        "AVMX9sHTyNVr4SjF3oRt",
            "AVMTc1fSyNVr4SjF3WpF",
            "AVMYuGLOyNVr4SjF3rKm"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If not then you need to update mapping for your type to be

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "YOUR_TYPE": {
      "_id": {
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use       **"script": "sortOrder.indexOf(doc['_id'].value)"**

Comment: how can i do this with elastica?

Comment: i had this error failed to run inline script [sortOrder.indexOf(doc["Id"].value)] using lang [groovy]

Comment: Can you post example of any of you documetns in index?